# jQuery attr() won't add an id to <li>

Tags: jquery, attr

When I load my webpage and run the below command in the JS console

```
$('#toRead li')[2]
```

I get the following returned:

```
<li class="bookToRead"> ... </li>
```

Which is what I expect. However when I tack on the attr method to add an id like so:

```
$('#toRead li')[2].attr('id', 'firstBook');
```

the following error is thrown--Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

From what I've read, this is the way to add an id to an element. I must be missing something.

Comment: Why do you want an element to have multiple `id`s in the first place?

Comment: The <li> doesn't have an id. It has a class. Hence:

    <li class="bookToRead"> ... </li>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an error because you are referencing a DOM element rather than a jQuery object.

If you use [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) api it will return a jQuery object:

```
$('#toRead li').eq(2).attr('id', 'firstBook');
```

Here you will set the `id` attribute of the 3rd returned `li` from your selector.

Comment: `eq()` is zero based. Should be `eq(1)`.

Comment: @BrianRay OP was also using index of 2  (also zero based)  - I matched this.

Comment: Thanks! That explains it nicely!

Answer (score 1):

`attr` is a jQuery object method - when you select the specified index of `[2]`, you're getting a DOM element back, so you can use `setAttribute`

```
$('#toRead li')[2].setAttribute('id', 'firstBook');
```

Comment: Good to know the Javascript method for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can do it this way

```
var bookToRead = $('#toRead li')[2];
$(bookToRead ).attr('id', 'firstBook');
```